# How to package or deliver updated shared libraries with an application

Tags: shared-libraries, rpm

I have an application A that I'm going to package up in an RPM.  This application depends on shared library L.  Most distributions have an older version of L.

The library L has issues being statically linked and must be delivered as a shared library.

My question is, how do I handle getting the current version of L delivered?

Do I package library L in my rpm with non-conflicting file names and link to those names?

Can i install library L in some alternate location and modify LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't want to modify `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. You could use an `rpath` in your libraries/binaries though.

Alternatively, if your version has a different soversion then there isn't any conflict and linking will just work and you can install them into the normal locations.

That being said I wouldn't do that and would probably go with the package-local `lib` directory and use an explicit `rpath` to that location.

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't be modifying the global LD_LIBRAY_PATH, I would modify it in a script that runs the application.  I wasn't aware of rpath, looking into that now.